# How can I propagate Pachira?

Tags: houseplants, propagation

I'm trying to save an indoor potted [Pachira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachira) (probably *P. glabra*, "Money Tree") that has become "leggy" from <strike>years</strike> decades of mistreatment. I'd like to take a cutting and start a new tree.

A few sites suggest rooting hormone (e.g., [this one](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/propagate-pachira-aquatica-cutting-water-soil-91004.html)) but others (e.g., [this one](http://forums.botanicalgarden.ubc.ca/threads/pachira-aquatica.42763/)) seem to suggest that it's not absolutely necessary. I'd like to avoid the rooting hormone (most practically because I haven't got any handy...) but I'll do so if necessary. I've only got a couple candidate stalks to work with.

I had hoped it would root/propagate easily in the fashion of [Schefflera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schefflera), since it seems to have superficial resemblance, but seems to have no relation.

I have propagated many plants before in this way (so I have some experience), but never Pachira, so I'm most interested in suggestions particular to this plant. Must I use rooting hormone, or will it sprout on its own -- or perhaps in a jar with a rooting Schefflera? What other techniques might I use to ensure success? E.g., let it dry, where to cut relative to a node, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it has milky sap, a rooting hormone is a more reliable way to propagate from cuttings. I don't know the species, sorry, but if the host plant you are taking cuttings from is doing poorly, it might be better to take cuttings from a healthier host. Cuttings are like cloning, the new plant will have the same characteristics as the host plant (both desirable and undesired).

Comment: I understand what propagation is (concept, consequences, etc.) and have some experience, so I'm hoping for suggestions more specific to this species. The milky sap statement (e.g., Ficus?) is something I didn't know, and might be helpful here. I can't immediately find a link to anything like that. Can you say more about why milky sap is a determining factor for propagation technique?

Comment: Plants with milky sap tend to be harder to propagated from cuttings, I think the actual sap may have something to do with a reduced striking rate for new roots. I did a horticultural certificate a few years ago and when we were learning how to make cuttings, we used a rooting hormone (in powder form) on any plants with a milky sap. To my knowledge this is standard practice in nurseries.